# Android: Taking photo and saving that image in internal/external storage with specific name by programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

I'm working on Camera side.
Android: Taking photo and saving that image in internal/external storage with specific name of the device by programmatically?
**When i click on save button it not storing in storage please help me** 
Here is my code:

**Main Activity is**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button cButton, cSavaBtn;
    ImageView ivCamera;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        cSavaBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        ivCamera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        cButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Camera Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                Intent cIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cIntent, 0);

            }
        });

        cSavaBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Save btn Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
               AfterSaveClick();
            }
        });

    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ivCamera.setImageBitmap(bm);

    }
    public void AfterSaveClick() {

        ivCamera.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bm = ivCamera.getDrawingCache();


        OutputStream fOut = null;

        try {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Correct now",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "sharathFolder" + File.separator);
            root.mkdirs();
            File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Correct end now",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        try {
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**XML file is:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:text="Camera API"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="camera"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SAVE"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**My Manifest file:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kgsharat"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you facing any error?

Comment: No i'm not facing any error but it not creating folder in internal/external storge and not saving clicked image.

Comment: Which device/OS version have you tested this on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Clicking Save button, you have to call this method. It works fine for me

```
public void AfterSaveClick() {

        ivCamera.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bm = ivCamera.getDrawingCache();


        OutputStream fOut = null;

        try {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Correct now",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "sharathFolder" + File.separator);
            root.mkdirs();
            File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Correct end now",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        try {
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String storeSdCard(Bitmap bitmap) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (status.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "FolderName");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        String filename = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        File file = new File(root, filename + ".jpg");

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            if (fos != null) {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fos);
                fos.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Uri muri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        String path = muri.getPath();

        return path;
    }
    return null;
}
```

After you got the bitmap, by using this method you can store the image in internal memory. And give permissions in manifest file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks.. @rams  but in my code only its working fine, but not stored Immediately...it will take some time to create... why ?? hav any idea..??

Comment: Welcome..In my application it is working fine. bitmap stored instantly.